# Why won't Xcode recognize iPhone in Big Sur update in Build/Run-time?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, macos-big-sur

been working on a couple apps for quite some time now and everything was going perfectly. Recently I updated to Big Sur, and using Xcode 12.2 and building and running on my iPhone has become an absolute nightmare. I plug my phone in via USB and my phone is charging, click "Trust" when the alert shows, but Xcode won't recognize it, and even when it does recognize it, I try to run it and it takes like 10 minutes, other times it is "Copying Cache" for 10+ minutes, or "iPhones not Connected/iPhone is Busy: Waiting for Device". I've found some posts on reddit and stack overflow about similar issues and have followed steps there (delete derived date, delete DeviceSupport folder) and they don't seem to work. I've tried all 4 ports on my MacBook Pro and its always the same.

I'm trying on just a VERY small and simple app that I've just started on, and its doing the same thing, so its not an issue with dependencies, pods, etc.

I've deleted and redownloaded Xcode, I've tried the Xcode 12.3 beta, I've restarted my computer and my phone multiple times, and nothing seems to be helping.

Anybody here run into this? Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: I've never had the issue long term but have you tried deleting the device in the "Devices" tab in "Add Additional Simulators...". Also, make sure you are using an Apple cable. I've had a ton of issues with other brands.

Comment: Yeah using a real Apple cable. I've tried to Unpair Device multiple times but nothing ever happens when I click it.

Comment: On the phone Settings>Developer>Clear Trusted Computers. Then unpair the device and clear/clean everything.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on Unpair Device in the Devices and Simulators screen. Its very strange.